# if statement only runs on second key down

Tags: javascript, html, keydown, onkeydown

Trying to figure out why the if statement here only runs on the second time a user presses a key down. I'm trying to get it to run starting on the first key down.

Function:

```
const commentFieldHasText = () => {
    const commentInput = document.querySelector('.add-comment')
    console.log('runs first keypress')

    if (commentInput.value) {
      console.log('only runs second keypress')
    }
  }
```

Input:

```
 <input 
   className="add-comment"
   placeholder="Add a public comment" 
   onKeyDown={() => commentFieldHasText()}
 />
```

**Additional Info:** onKeyPress doesn't give expected functionality either. onKeyUp does though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because the `keydown` and `keypress` events occur *before* the actual key is typed.

To fix this, try using the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) or `keyup` events.